# Add memoization to recursive function, Python

Tags: python, function, recursion, matrix, memoization

Python. First of all, I did recursive code that find how many the shortests paths has matrix, path from last cell in matrix to frist cell in matrix. This is my code that work:

```
def matrix_explorer(n,m):
    """
    Recursive function that find number of the shortest paths from beginning cell of matrix to last cell
    :param n: Integer, how many rows has matrix
    :param m: Integer, how many columns has matrix
    :return: Number of the shortests paths
    """
    count=0     # Number of paths
    if n == 1 or m == 1:    # Stop condition, if one of cells is equal to 1
        return count+1    # Add to number of paths 1
    else:
        return matrix_explorer(n-1, m) + matrix_explorer(n, m-1)   # Go to cell above or left to current cell
```

I need to add memoization to this recursive function. What I have, but it's not actually working:

```
def matrix_explorer_cache(n ,m):
    dictionary = {}
    count = 0
    if n == 1 or m == 1:
        return count+1
    else:
        dictionary[n][m] = matrix_explorer_cache(n-1, m) + matrix_explorer_cache(n, m-1)
        return dictionary[n][m]
```

Comment: Unless you have a requirement to write your own, you could look into the `cache` decorator in the `functools` module

Comment: Also, there are some memoize decorators in the [decorator library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary) that you could probably adapt.